# BlueCove Bluetooth Device Discovery

Tags: java, bluetooth, jsr82

I've built and ran the RemoteDeviceDiscovery sample project for [BlueCove 2.1.1](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/overview-summary.html#DeviceDiscovery). The program will discover all discoverable bluetooth devices but it will also report in deviceDiscovered() devices that were once paired before.

Is there a way to ONLY discover devices around you (like in Android)? The code below returns BOTH discovered devices and paired devices...

```
public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
            System.out.println("Device " + btDevice.getBluetoothAddress() + " found");
            devicesDiscovered.addElement(btDevice);
            try {
                System.out.println("     name " + btDevice.getFriendlyName(false));
            } catch (IOException cantGetDeviceName) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - use http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/RemoteDevice.html#isTrustedDevice() to filter unpaired devices (or paired devices if you wish to).

Comment: the problem is that ... how can you find all devices that are in range whether they are paired or not ?